# Crystal automated unit tests at compilation

Tags: unit-testing, crystal-lang

In my understanding, Crystal can perform Unit tests while compiling but I could not find much info on them.

Can Crystal perform Unit tests while compiling ? If yes how can I implement them in a new project and how do I give them arguments ?

Ex : if some tests require internet can I somehow send / give / set an argument to desactivate them if I have no internet ?

Comment: BTW, you may want to check the Gitter channel (https://gitter.im/crystal-lang/crystal). The people are very helpful and you can get quick answers to your questions.

Comment: they are, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not exactly an answer to your question, [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) may work for you. Here's how I have set it up, and works very well. Although not a Crystal shard, it's a Ruby gem that works great in dev environment.

Whenever I save a file, guard runs all the specs (which would be your unit tests). I gather that all the code is compiled before running.

Although Crystal Spec (https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/Spec.html) does not provide tagging, you can specify a folder: `crystal spec spec/units`. You can put the specs that require internet in another folder.

Another approach you can use is to write a bash (or Ruby) script that compiles and runs the specs.

BTW, you probably don't want to use the internet for you specs, unit or otherwise. You can mock them using [Webmock](https://github.com/manastech/webmock.cr), or by re-opening your classes in the test environment. I have been using the latter approach, and it works well.

Answer (score 3):

This article gives a good overview over Crystal Specs: http://ruby-journal.com/crystal/testing-whirlwind-tour-in-crystal-lang/

I'd recommend to never depend on outside connections for any spec. Specifically unit tests should be reliable and dont just fail because of outside influences (no connection, routing problems, API changes, whatever).
Set up mocks for external requests to mimic the essential behaviour of the real target.
Only integration tests might require some real API access.

Answer (score 1):

You can find documentation on Crystal's `Spec` library [here](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/Spec.html).